# Pointwise, uniform, normal and $L^p$ convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-nx}}{1+n^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, lp-spaces

Study the pointwise, uniform, normal and on $L^p$ convergence of the series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-nx}}{1+n^2}$$

**My approach**

Let $f_n(x)=\frac{e^{-nx}}{1+n^2}$, it's easy to show that:

1. $f_n(x)\ge 0 \ \ \ \forall x\in\mathbb{R}$;
2. $\lim_{n\to+\infty}f_n(x)=0 \iff x\in [0,+\infty)$
3. $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-nx}}{1+n^2}\le\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n^2+1}\le\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}<+\infty$

where the first inequality of (3) is true for $x\ge0$. From (3) I know that the series is normally convergent on $[0,+\infty)$, hence it converges pointwise and uniformly on the $[0,+\infty)$.

Now $\sum\frac{e^{-nx}}{n^2+1}$ is a normal convergent series in $[0,+\infty)$ because $\sum\frac{1}{n^2}$ converges.

Let $S_k(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{k}\frac{e^{-nx}}{1+n^2}$ and $S(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-nx}}{1+n^2}$, how can I prove that

$$\|S-S_k\|_{p}^{p}=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\left|\sum_{n=k+1}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-nx}}{n^2+1}\right|^pdx \longrightarrow 0$$ for $k\to +\infty$.

My first idea is to use the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem: if so, the limit operator goes trough the integral, hence $\|S-S_k\|_{p}^{p}\to 0$ for $k\to +\infty$ because $$\sum_{n=k+1}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-nx}}{n^2+1}$$ is the tail of a convergent series (then $\sum_{n=k+1}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-nx}}{n^2+1}\to 0$ for $k\to+\infty$).

Now I have many troubles to find $g(x)$ such that $\left|\sum_{n=k+1}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-nx}}{n^2+1}\right|^p\le g(x)$ and $g(x)\in L^1([0,+\infty))$

I try this:

$$\sum_{n=k+1}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-nx}}{n^2+1}\le\sum_{n=k+1}^{+\infty}e^{-n x}=\frac{e^{-(k+1)x}}{1-e^{-x}}$$

and now I'm stuck because of  $1-e^{-x}$.

Every other inequalities I found are useless to find a proper $g(x)$. Maybe there is a easier way to solve this. Need help. Thanks.

---

**Edit**: This part

> where the first inequality of (3) is true for $x\ge0$. From (3) I know
>   that the series is normally convergent on $[0,+\infty)$, hence it
>   converges pointwise and uniformly on the $[0,+\infty)$

is logically incorrect, in fact 3. must be $$3. \ \frac{e^{-nx}}{n^2+1}\le\frac{1}{n^2+1}\le\frac{1}{n^2}$$ and so $\sum\frac{e^{-nx}}{n^2+1}$ is a normal convergent series in $[0,+\infty)$ because $\sum\frac{1}{n^2}$ converges.

Comment: What do you call « total convergence »?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Sorry, it's the translation of the italian expression: "convergenza totale". I know now that in English, the "total convergence" is called "Weierstrass M-test". More precisely, in Italy we say that a series $\sum f_n(x)$ is "totalmente convergente" in a set $E$ if and only $\exists (M_n)_n\ge 0$ such that $|f_n(x)|\le M_n \ \ \ \forall x\in E$ and $\sum M_n<+\infty$.

Comment: Another English way should be "normal convergence"

Comment: Thanks @LucaMac.

Comment: Your reasoning for 3. is incorrect.

Comment: @zhw Why? $e^{-nx}\le 1 \ \ \ \forall x\in[0,+\infty)$ so $\frac{e^{-nx}}{n^2+1}\le\frac{1}{n^2+1}\le\frac{1}{n^2}\ \ \ \forall n\ge 1.$

Comment: Now it's correct! Notice the difference between this and what you wrote in 3.

Comment: @zhw, from the double inequality it follows that $\sum \frac{e^{-nx}}{n^2+1}\le\sum\frac{1}{n^2+1}\le\sum\frac{1}{n^2}$, right? It is a conseguence of the squeeze theorem. Is it correct?

Comment: Of course. But that doesn't prove uniform convergence. What you wrote in the comment proves uniform convergence by Weierstrass M.

Comment: @zhw. ?!...!! O_O you're right! Gosh, I should have paid more attention. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. It's a common mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\left|\sum_{n=k+1}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-nx}}{n^2+1}\right|^p\le e^{-px} \cdot \left(\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{(n^2+1)}\right)^p = c^p \cdot e^{-px}$$
And $$ \int_0^{+\infty} c^p \cdot e^{-px} = \frac{c^p}{p} < + \infty $$
So you can use dominated convergence theorem and show the $L^p$ convergence.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how you did it (+1) anyway!

Comment: I just used $e^{-nx} \leq e^{-x}$ for any $n \geq 1$

Comment: That was ok. I didn't understand why in the second term of inequality (RHS) $n\ge 1$...but now is clear! Thank you so much! (I am a donkey)

Comment: Well, I just increased the number of things to sum. I had to do so because $g$ must not depend on $k$.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Well done sir, chapeau! Can you use another name for the sum of $\left[\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{1}{(n^2+1)}\right]^p$? $k$ and $k(p)$ can be confusing.

Comment: Yes, you're right! I have edited my post.